# Select rows based on grouping in same table

Tags: t-sql

Sorry about the lame Title... If I could summarize this in a few words I might have had better luck finding an existing solution here!

I have a table that simplified looks like this:

```
ID       PRODUCT
___      _________
100      Savings  
200      Mortgage  
200      Visa  
300      Mortgage  
300      Savings
```

I need to select rows based on the product of each ID. For example, I can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM table1
WHERE Product NOT IN ('Savings', 'Chequing')
```

This would return:

```
ID
___
200
300
```

However, in the case of ID 300 they do have Savings so I actually do not want this returned. In plain English I want to

Select * from table1 where 'Savings' and 'Chequing' are not the product for any row with that ID.

Desired result in this case would be one row with ID 200 since they do not have Savings or Chequing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the rows that match the item you do not want to match then compare therr ids

e.g.

```
select distinct id from table1 where id not in (
  SELECT ID
  FROM table1
  WHERE Product IN ('Savings', 'Chequing')
)
```

Comment: Worked lick a charm. Nice simple logic. Thanks.

Comment: I think that nullable is not an issue here if product is null, but will be of id can be but making id nullable is a very bad use of column names. SQL server is reliable over NULLS they never equal anything. I assumed not null as that is the sane way to do anything. If a column is null I assume you mention it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.Poduct IN ('Savings', 'Chequing')
    AND t2.ID = t1.ID
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de4d4/3/0)</kbd>

Worth reading: [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)